# Which partition to use for Suse 12.3 bootloader?

Tags: linux, bootloader, opensuse, grub2

When installing opensuse 12.3 a partition for the bootloader should be specified.
When I previously installed ubuntu for example I set the bootloader to be installed on the entire drive : e.g. sda (and not sda1 or sda2 which are partitions)
I do not find this option in the suse installation.

The only option i have is to create  a new partition which will have the mount point as /boot/efi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want UEFI installation. 
Do not mix boot partition where GRUB resides, and EFI boot partition which is OS-independent. EFI partition is FAT32 only. You should carefully research this topic before continuing. 
For OpenSuse you must make a EFI partition of 100 Mb of FAT32, and, they recommend, a boot partition of 100Mb too, in EXT4. Althoug, you should be sure that your have booted your installation media in UEFI mode. And use grub2-efi bootloader. And HDD must have GPT partition table, not MBR. 
See? Better research it carefully prior to installation.

Comment: so ubuntu does not need an efi boot partition?